# How can I fix "Overloaded member function not found" error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I keep getting the following error:

> `"overloaded function not found in 'pizza'"`

This referring to `void outputDescription` and `double computePrice` functions, below. I can't figure out what is wrong.

I am a beginner to C++ but the code looks right. This is for class. I'm supposed to have at least 1 mutator function and 1 accessor function, a function to compute price and a function to output the description of the pizza.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class pizza
{
    public:
        void getOrder (string, string, int, int) ;
        void outputDescription (string&, string&, int&, int&) const;
        double computePrice (string&, int&, int&) const;
    private:
        string type;
        string size;
        int pepperoni;
        int cheese;
};

int main ()
{
    pizza customerpizza;
    double price;
    string type;
    string size;
    int pepperoni;
    int cheese;

    customerpizza.getOrder (type, size, pepperoni, cheese);
    customerpizza.outputDescription (type, size, pepperoni, cheese);
    price = customerpizza.computePrice (size, pepperoni, cheese);

    cout << "Total cost is $" << price << ".\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void pizza::getOrder (string type, string size, int pepperoni, int cheese)
{
    int pizzaType;
    int pizzaSize;

    cout << "Please choose 1 for deep dish, 2 for hand tossed, or 3\n";     cout << " for pan pizza.\n";
    cin >> pizzaType;

    switch(pizzaType)
    {
        case 1: type = "deep dish";
        break;
        case 2: type = "hand tossed";
        break;
        case 3: type = "pan";
        break;
        default: cout << "You entered an invalid choice. Please\n";              
                 cout << " enter 1 for deep dish, 2 for hand\n";             
                 cout << " tossed, or 3 for pan pizza.\n";
    }

    cout << "Please choose 1 for small, 2 for medium, or 3 for\n"; 
    cout << " large pizza.\n";
    cin >> pizzaSize;

    switch(pizzaSize)
    {
        case 1: size = "small";
        break;
        case 2: size = "medium";
        break;
        case 3: size = "large";
        break;
        default: cout << "You entered an invalid choice. Please\n";
                 cout << " enter 1 for small, 2 for medium, or\n";
                 cout << " 3 for large pizza.\n";
    }

    cout << "How many pepperoni servings on this pizza?\n";
    cin >> pepperoni;

    cout << "How many cheese servings on this pizza?\n";
    cin >> cheese;
}

void pizza::outputDescription (string type, string size, int pepperoni, int cheese) 
{
    cout << "You ordered a " << size << << type << " pizza with \n"; 
    cout << pepperoni << " servings of pepperoni and "<< cheese << endl;   
    cout << "servings of cheese.\n";

}

double pizza::computePrice (string size, int pepperoni, int cheese)
{
    double price;

    if (size = "small")
    {
        price = 10 + (2 * (pepperoni + cheese));
    }

    else if (size = "medium")
    {
        price = 14 + (2 * (pepperoni  + cheese));
    }

    else if (size = "large")
    {
        price = 17 + (2 * (pepperoni + cheese));
    }

    return price;
}
```

Comment: Since this is for class, you're going to have to learn how to do object orientation properly. Your `getOrder`, `outputDescription` and `computePrice` functions should have no arguments. They should be using the member variables you declared in `pizza` not arguments. The way you have written it you could delete the pizza member variables and your code would work just the same.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the full error message from your compiler as part of your question.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've never used this forum because I assumed answers wouldn't come in a timely manner but, boy am I surprised. You folks are awesome and very helpful. Unfortunately, I didn't see your replies until after I found part of my problem. I got it to work but John, thank you for your comment about object functions. I reworked it with your suggestion to not send arguments and the program works great.

Comment: Actually, John, I thought I had it but when compiling it again I've having trouble. When I don't send arguments to the functions I get the message.

error C2660: 'pizza::getOrder' : function does not take 0 arguments
error C2660: 'pizza::outputDescription' : function does not take 0 arguments
error C2660: 'pizza::computePrice' : function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: @tysowell: `function does not take 0 arguments` means that you have removed the arguments from the invocation but haven't removed the arguments from the declaration. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 10):

You declare your member `outputDescription()` function this way:

```
void outputDescription (string&, string&, int&, int&) const;
//                      ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
```

But the definition you provide has this signature:

```
void pizza::outputDescription (
    string type, string size, int pepperoni, int cheese) const
//  ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^       ^^^            ^^^         ^^^^^
//                REFERENCES ARE MISSING!                Qualifier!
```

You forgot to use the reference in the function definition, and you forgot to add the `const` qualifier. The signature used in a member function definition must match the signature of a member function declaration, and yours doesn't. Just make those parameter types *references* to `string` and `int`, and add the `const` qualifier, consistently with the way you declare the function.

Same problem for the `computePrice()` member function. Here is how you declare it:

```
double computePrice (string&, int&, int&) const;
//                   ^^^^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^
```

And here is its definition:

```
double pizza::computePrice (string size, int pepperoni, int cheese) const
//                          ^^^^^^       ^^^            ^^^         ^^^^^
//                              REFERENCES ARE MISSING!             Qualifier!
```

Of course, the solution is the same.

Comment: Don't forget the `const`-qualifier on the methods.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've never used this forum because I assumed answers wouldn't come in a timely manner but, boy am I surprised. You folks are awesome and very helpful. Unfortunately, I didn't see your replies until after I found part of my problem. I got it to work but John, thank you for your comment about object functions. I reworked it with your suggestion to not send arguments and the program works great. Andy, thank you for your answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Error is due to your **methods signatures in declaration (header file) and defenition are different** (you forgot &)

Answer (score 1):

Your method has the signature

```
void outputDescription(string&, string&, int&, int&) const;
```

but you are defining it as

```
void pizza::outputDescription(string type, string size, int pepperoni, int cheese)
```

For one, the parameter types do not match and you're not qualifying the latter as a const member function.

Since your methods don't match, the compiler tries to find a suitable overload which if fails to find, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comments elsewhere into an answer…

The actual solution is to remove all of these arguments (`string type, string size, int pepperoni, int cheese`), since they needlessly [shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2804880/78845) member variables (as was pointed out by [John in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467115/how-can-i-fix-overloaded-member-function-not-found-error#comment21888469_15467115)) and should have been pointed out by your compiler!

You also need to ensure that your [cv-qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) on the methods are the same for the declarations and the definitions.

As such your declarations should be:

```
    void getOrder();
    void outputDescription() const;
    double computePrice() const;
```

And the definitions should look like:

```
void pizza::getOrder()

void pizza::outputDescription() const

double pizza::computePrice() const
```

This would leave the invocations in [`main()`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Cg5yb$1) looking a lot neater:

```
int main()
{
    pizza customerpizza;
    customerpizza.getOrder();
    customerpizza.outputDescription();
    double price = customerpizza.computePrice();

    cout << "Total cost is $" << price << ".\n";
}
```

There are a couple of other things to watch out for, too...

In `computePrice()`, you're confusing equality (**`==`**) with assignment (**`=`**). That is `if (size = "small")` should be `if (size == "small")` and similarly for the other `size`s).

In `outputDescription()`, the following line is missing something:

```
cout << "You ordered a " << size << << type << " pizza with \n"; 
// --------------------------------^
// Did you mean to include a space? (' ')?
```

Learning to read and understand compiler errors (and warnings) is a vital part of learning C++. Keep practising!

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been well answered by others, but I would like to point out two other problems with your code.

1. Member function `void getOrder (string, string, int, int) ;` should use the references of the variables, otherwise you are not able to set the values of your member values.
2. in member function `double pizza::computePrice`, you should use `if (!size.compare("small"))` in stead of `if (size = "small")`.